# Importing module from js file in Webpack 2

Tags: webpack, require, webpack-2

I am trying to use the following syntax in Webpack 2:

```
import someSvc = require("./some.svc.js");
```

But I am getting the error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module './some.svc.js'.
```

What am I doing wrong?! How do I import my js module in Webpack 2?

For the sake of thoroughness, I boiled my project down to the tiniest possible example, and will provide the files below:

## webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
  var config = {};
  config.entry = { 'app': './src/main.ts' };
  config.output = {
    path: root('dist'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js'
  };
  config.module = {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader']
      }
    ]
  };
  return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^0.9.5",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

## tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

## src/main.ts

```
import someSvc = require("./some.svc.js");
```

## src/some.svc.js

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports.config = function (conf) {
        return { abc: 123 };
    };
}
```

Stick these files together, run `webpack` and you should see the same error.

Am I missing something simple to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

After struggling with this for far too long, as usual writing the SO post somehow triggered my brain or something.

Coming from SystemJs to Webpack I didn't expect the `require` to change at all.

Nevertheless, I fixed this with two changes.

This line:

`import someSvc = require("./some.svc.js");`

Becomes:

`var someSvc = require("./some.svc.js");`

And running this (I am using TypeScript 2.0):

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`